# Can the standard knapsack problem be solved using LLL?

Tags: knapsack-problems, lattices

It is well-known that the Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem can be solved using the LLL algorithm. In the Merkle-Hellman knapsack cryptosystem, we're trying to find a solution $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ such that

\begin{align}
\sum w_i x_i &= K,
\end{align}

where the $w_i$ are integer weights. Is it possible to find an approximate solution to the standard 0-1 knapsack problem

\begin{gather}
\text{maximize } \sum v_i x_i \\
\text{subject to} \sum w_i x_i \le K,\quad x_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{gather}

Using LLL?